# How to get elbow IK constraints to work properly?

Tags: bones, constraints

So far I have 4 IKs on my rig: 2 arm and 2 elbow. The arm IKs work fine but the eblow IKs are wonky. When translated, the elbow IK is hinged by the arm IK. If I set the elbow IK to chain length > 0, they simply stop working entirely. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

File: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the bicept Ik chain to one, it works pretty well, but generally this kind of rig is constructed with only one IK: the forearm pointing to the arm IK, then you can use the elbow IK bone as the pole target of the single IK constraint.
Don't forget to set the right pole angle (in my example 180 degrees).

[image]

Comment: So I've done that except changed the chain length to 1 and angle to 0. How do I go about making the IK to move the arm then since this now only moves from elbow down?

Comment: In your original rig you could set the upper IK chain to one (from elbow to shoulder) and the lower IK chain to 2 (from wrist to shoulder). In my rig i've set only one IK chain and - as it is in the image - the chain lenght has to be 2 (form wrist to shoulder). In pose mode, after posing the wrist, you can pose the elbow pole bone to set the position of the elbow. Search for free Nathan Vegdahl amazing serie of video tutorial about rigging, they are perfectly explained.